# How can I view the history of a branch that isn't checked out?

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

How can I view the history of a branch or a commit, that isn't the one I've currently got checked out?

If I'm on `master`, and I want to see the log of a sidebranch, or a commit, or a tag, then in the command line this is very easy:

```
git log $BRANCH_NAME
git log $COMMIT_HASH
git log $TAG
```

...but I'm not finding any way to do that in SourceTree.

The best I've found is:

- Check out the thing whose log I want to see. This obviously touches a whole bunch of files unnecessarily.
- If the log view is displaying all branches, I can jump to a branch or a commit in the log view -- but, I'll have *all* branches in the log view; I can't see *just* the branch/history that interests me.

Am I missing something? I'm having a hard time understanding how you can even use git effectively without being able to navigate your history and zoom in on things.

Comment: All commits and branches can be viewed in the Log/History tab for a repository.  Check the dropdown above the graph to make sure that "All Branches" is selected, rather than "Current Branch."

Comment: @BJMyers : I want to see the log for *one* branch, not for *all* branches.

Comment: Gotcha, I misunderstood.  AFAIK SourceTree does not let you filter to a single branch unless it is your current branch.